# Query Formula to import a few columns from a raw data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a raw data in Sheet 1 with 10 columns out of which column B has the client name entered in it. Sheet 2 refers to the list of client name whose data is actually needed from the Raw data. I would like to use a query formula here.

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A:G, "SELECT * WHERE A IN (SELECT A FROM 'Sheet2'!A1:A5)", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Google-sheet `QUERY()` function doesn't support `IN` clause like other standard ***SQL***. You can use `matches` operator instead. Give a try to-

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A:G,"select * where A matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,UNIQUE('Sheet2'!A1:A5)) & "'")
```